# What are the limits for the left-closing/right-closing parameter for the cut function in R?

Tags: r

So, I was learning about linear regression and came across the cut function. I know it defaults to breaks being right closed (i.e. (x-y]) and setting right=FALSE makes it left closed (i.e. [x-y)). Is there a way to make the cuts with both closed (i.e. [x-y]) or both open (i.e. (x-y))? I realize it's probably not practical, but I'm just curious as to the answer for this question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no.

To understand it we must come back to the base of what the `cut` function is for:

> `cut` divides the range of `x` into intervals and codes the values in `x` according to which interval they fall. The leftmost interval corresponds to level one, the next leftmost to level two and so on.

From: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/cut

And as for that purpose, each element of `x` must belong to one and only one group within the cut definition. A special case that you got that [x-y] right out of the box is for the first group where you have `right=TRUE` & `include.lowest=TRUE`. Other than that it depend on how you interpret the group or labels them.

```
x <- seq(1, 100, by = 1)
cut(x, breaks = c(1, 25, 50, 75, 100), include.lowest = TRUE, right = TRUE,
  labels = c("[1, 25]", "[26, 50]", "[51, 75]", "[76, 100]"))
```

Produce a cut with this levels - so this maybe what you want? A labels instead?

```
Levels: [1, 25] [26, 50] [51, 75] [76, 100]
```

Though this would be correctly name for the case with all integer but when you got real number with decimal points then the manual labels like this is not very accurate any more.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need arbitrary limits, you could use (my) `santoku` package:

```r
library(santoku)

# left_vec is TRUE where a break is left-closed like ...)[...
# so this creates breaks like [-Inf, 1) [1, 2] (2, 3) [3, 4) [4, Inf ]
breaks <- brk_manual(1:4, left_vec = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE))

x <- seq(0, 5, 0.5)
chopped <- chop(x, breaks, extend = TRUE)
data.frame(x, chopped)
```

which gives

```
 x   chopped
1  0.0 [-Inf, 1)
2  0.5 [-Inf, 1)
3  1.0    [1, 2]
4  1.5    [1, 2]
5  2.0    [1, 2]
6  2.5    (2, 3)
7  3.0    [3, 4)
8  3.5    [3, 4)
9  4.0 [4, Inf ]
10 4.5 [4, Inf ]
11 5.0 [4, Inf ]
```